# How do I send a message to a specific channel? Discord/Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I send a message to a specific channel?
Why am I getting this Error ? My `ChannelID` is right

Code:

```
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
channel = client.get_channel('693503765059338280')



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot wurde gestartet: ' + client.user.name)
#wts        
@client.command()
async def test(ctx,name_schuh,preis,festpreis):
    await channel.send(discord.Object(id='693503765059338280'),"Name:" + name_schuh +"\n Preis: " + preis +"\n Festpreis: " + festpreis)
```

Error:

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is because `channel = client.get_channel()` is called before the bot is connected, meaning it will always return `None` as it cannot see any channels (not connected).

Move this to inside your command function to have it get the `channel` object as the command is called.

Also note that since version 1.0, [snowflakes are now `int` type instead of `str` type](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#snowflakes-are-int). This means you need to use `client.get_channel(693503765059338280)` instead of `client.get_channel('693503765059338280')`.

```
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot wurde gestartet: ' + client.user.name)

@client.command()
async def test(ctx,name_schuh,preis,festpreis):
    channel = client.get_channel(693503765059338280)
    await channel.send("Name:" + name_schuh +"\n Preis: " + preis +"\n Festpreis: " + festpreis)

client.run('token')
```

Answer (score -1):

`client` and `channel` are out of scope. You can use `global` keyword for a dirty hack:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
channel = client.get_channel(693503765059338280)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global client
    print('Bot wurde gestartet: ' + client.user.name)

#wts        
@client.command()
async def test(ctx,name_schuh,preis,festpreis):
    global client
    global channel
    await channel.send(discord.Object(id=693503765059338280),"Name:" + name_schuh +"\n Preis: " + preis +"\n Festpreis: " + festpreis)
```

But the better alternative would be a handler class that holds the instances.

Comment: Won't work. `channel = client.get_channel()` is returning `None` in the above code

Comment: Will still return `None` as it's called before the bot has connected. It can't see any channels so `get_channel` will always return `None`