# How i make my bot only response if it is in the right channel

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey i tried this but it didnt work the bot still answers in any channel idk why if you can please help me would be AWESOME

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'hey' in message.content.lower():
        if 'i' in message.content.lower():
            message.channel.name.startswith("ticket")
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``test``', color=0x001fff )
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


    if 'test' in message.content.lower():
        message.channel.name.startswith("ticket")
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``hi``', color=0x001fff )
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

This is my Command

Comment: Which channel do you want it to answer in?

Comment: in a channel that starts with ticket like i did the function but it dont work here the code if you need it message.channel.name.startswith("ticket")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I send a message to a specific channel? Discord/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989729/how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel-discord-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `message.channel.name.startswith("ticket")` outside an if statement. This won't do anything.
Replacing it with `if(message.channel.name.startswith("ticket")):` actually checks if the channel name starts with "ticket". And you need to indent the code which should be executed. Below you can see i have fixed the code for you.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'hey' in message.content.lower():
        if 'i' in message.content.lower():
            if(message.channel.name.startswith("ticket")): #This line
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``test``', color=0x001fff )
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


    if 'test' in message.content.lower():
        message.channel.name.startswith("ticket")
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'test',description=f'**test** : ``hi``', color=0x001fff )
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```